# How to return tokens from Flask after authentication to Watson Assistant?

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have developed a user management system using Flask using [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/). 
I would like to add a Watson chatbot to the page, and it should check if the user is authenticated or not. This will be done inside Flask-Security in its login module as follows:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Here we use a class of some kind to represent and validate our
    # client-side form data. For example, WTForms is a library that will
    # handle this for us, and we use a custom LoginForm to validate.
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Login and validate the user.
        # user should be an instance of your `User` class
        login_user(user)

        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')

        next = flask.request.args.get('next')
        # is_safe_url should check if the url is safe for redirects.
        # See http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/62/ for an example.
        if not is_safe_url(next):
            return flask.abort(400)

        return flask.redirect(next or flask.url_for('index'))
    return flask.render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Is it possible when a user starts asking questions from the chat interface (e.g. asking from the date of registration in the system) we redirect him/her to the login page of Flask and after authentication, we get back to conversation dialog and pull data related to the authenticated user (e.g. the record timestamp of user profile)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Any specifics? Please edit your question to make it a specific programming-related question.

Comment: @data_henrik The registration and user management system is build using https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. How we can redirect users fro chat dialog to login and then continue the conversation?

Comment: Any code I can comment on? Your question is too broad right now.

Comment: @data_henrik make it even more specific. An example is the following service, when the user ask for "View Bill" it redirect to login, and after login it shows the bill related to the user:
https://www.koodomobile.com/help/

Answer (score -1):

See the [architecture diagram for Watson Assistant in the app context](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant/index.html#index). Watson Assistant is or can be just one of several services for a solution. Typically, your app would drive a dialog, a conversation, by repeatedly [sending a message to Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant) and obtaining the response.

Your Flask app handles the overall flow, the authentication, and how the chat data (maybe as a chat window) is embedded into the UI. See [IBM Cloud App ID](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-key-concepts#key-concepts) for different authentication flows. This [IBM Cloud tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/serverless-github-traffic-analytics.html) is based on Flask and implements OIDC with App ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I think it does not work like what you described. If you look at the example project, (https://www.koodomobile.com/help/) you can see the assistant after receiving a phone number (e.g. 2022228455), will show you a link to "Sign In" page. Then if you click on sign in and get to your account, it will return back you to the same chat dialog and afterward, you can ask questions about your account such as viewing billing history. My question is how they implemented this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking specific programming questions, not teaching general programming. There are various authentication flows that can be implemented, see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-key-concepts#key-concepts I added some links above.